# import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core'; error

Tags: angular

I use vs code to start the project code:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation ,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'
import { Helpers } from '../../../helpers'

declare let mLayout: any
@Component({
    selector: "app-breadcrumb",
    templateUrl: "./breadcrumb.component.html",
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    constructor() {

    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {

    }
}
```

```html
<!-- BEGIN: Subheader -->
<div class="m-subheader">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="mr-auto">
            <h3 class="m-subheader__title m-subheader__title--separator">
                Alerts
            </h3>
            <ul class="m-subheader__breadcrumbs m-nav m-nav--inline">
                <li class="m-nav__item m-nav__item--home">
                    <a href="#" class="m-nav__link m-nav__link--icon">
                        <i class="m-nav__link-icon la la-home"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="m-nav__separator">
                    -
                </li>
                <li class="m-nav__item">
                    <a href="" class="m-nav__link">
      <span class="m-nav__link-text">
       Base
      </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="m-nav__separator">
                    -
                </li>
                <li class="m-nav__item">
                    <a href="" class="m-nav__link">
      <span class="m-nav__link-text">
       Alerts
      </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="m-dropdown m-dropdown--inline m-dropdown--arrow m-dropdown--align-right m-dropdown--align-push" data-dropdown-toggle="hover" aria-expanded="true">
                <a href="#" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn btn-lg btn-secondary  m-btn m-btn--outline-2x m-btn--air m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill  m-dropdown__toggle">
                    <i class="la la-plus m--hide"></i>
                    <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="m-dropdown__wrapper">
                    <span class="m-dropdown__arrow m-dropdown__arrow--right m-dropdown__arrow--adjust"></span>
                    <div class="m-dropdown__inner">
                        <div class="m-dropdown__body">
                            <div class="m-dropdown__content">
                                <ul class="m-nav">
                                    <li class="m-nav__section m-nav__section--first m--hide">
          <span class="m-nav__section-text">
           Quick Actions
          </span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="m-nav__item">
                                        <a href="" class="m-nav__link">
                                            <i class="m-nav__link-icon flaticon-share"></i>
                                            <span class="m-nav__link-text">
            Activity
           </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="m-nav__item">
                                        <a href="" class="m-nav__link">
                                            <i class="m-nav__link-icon flaticon-chat-1"></i>
                                            <span class="m-nav__link-text">
            Messages
           </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="m-nav__item">
                                        <a href="" class="m-nav__link">
                                            <i class="m-nav__link-icon flaticon-info"></i>
                                            <span class="m-nav__link-text">
            FAQ
           </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="m-nav__item">
                                        <a href="" class="m-nav__link">
                                            <i class="m-nav__link-icon flaticon-lifebuoy"></i>
                                            <span class="m-nav__link-text">
            Support
           </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="m-nav__separator m-nav__separator--fit"></li>
                                    <li class="m-nav__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--wide btn-sm">
                                            Submit
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: Subheader -->
```

> Debugger listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:14841/d3b75433-e088-44a2-b228-51a9183448d4 For help,
>   see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector Debugger attached.
>   /Users/haiming_yu/IdeaProjects/deal-albedo/albedo-boot-ui-angular/target/www/app/app/theme/layouts/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.component.js:10
>   import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

[code](https://github.com/somewhereMrli/albedo-boot/tree/master/albedo-boot-ui-angular)
I do not know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: Pls reformat your question and let us know what is your actual issue here.

Comment: Why is this upvoted twice? OP didnt even tell what the issue is.

Comment: I tried to do 'ng build' No problem. but use 'ng build --prod' to prompt the same information.I used IDEA before, there was no problem with it but vscode could not start it

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to do npm install?

Comment: I tried to do  'ng build'  No problem. but use 'ng build --prod' to prompt the same information.